# Django form: disabling submit button and re-enabling when done

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, forms

I have a highly customized voting form that's generated dynamically using Javascript and, once it's submitted, it redirects you to another page ("voted") that either a) reports what the user voted for upon a successful submission, or b) reports the error that occurred upon an unsuccessful submission. One possible error is if the voter name has already been used, in which case it instructs the user to choose a different name.

My problem is that, if the user double clicks the submit button, it successfully submits the vote but then it ends up doing an unsuccessful submission after that since the voter name was used twice (i.e. a double post occurs). The user ends up skipping the successful vote page entirely and it just looks like their original vote wasn't counted, saying that the name was already used.

The tag for my form looks like this:

```
<form id="formVote" name="formVote" action="{% url 'surveys:voted' survey.id %}" method="POST">
```

I would love to be able to disable the submit button upon submission, but I can't figure out how to do it with the above code. What I did try was tagging the form like this:

```
<form id="formVote" name="formVote" action="" method="POST">
```

And calling up a JQuery function to handle things:

```
$('#formVote').submit(function(e){

// disable vote button to prevent double submissions
document.getElementById('submit_vote_button').disabled = true;
document.getElementById('submit_vote_button').value = "Submitting...";

// submit the vote
$.post('{% url 'surveys:voted' survey.id %}', $(this).serialize(), function(data){
document.getElementById('submit_vote_button').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('submit_vote_button').value = "Submit Vote";
});

e.preventDefault();
});
```

And this works somewhat, but it doesn't actually redirect the user to the "voted" page when it finishes... it successfully submits the vote (or doesn't if there's an error) and just remains on the voting form page when it's done, giving the user zero feedback about what happened, despite the views.py voted view returning a render:

```
return render(request, 'surveys/voted.html', {
            'error_message': error_message,
            'voter_name': voter_name,
            'ranking_id_array_final': ranking_id_array_final,
            'survey_id': survey_id,
            'survey_opened': survey_opened,
        })
```

Similarly, HttpResponseRedirect didn't do anything when I tried it out.

What I need to have happen is:

1. Submit button is disabled
2. POST request is submitted
3. "Voted" page is loaded
4. Submit button is re-enabled (**in case the user presses the
       back button to submit another vote**)

Any guidance here would be appreciated, I feel like I'm making things more complicated than they need to be.

Answer (score 1):

You can display `data` variable content in a modal or floatting div to show what happened to the user. That variable holds the rendered html of your template (using all its logic with all params you pass to it)

Maybe you can use [jquery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) to accomplish this

The script should be

```
$.post('{% url 'surveys:voted' survey.id %}', $(this).serialize(), function(data){
    document.getElementById('submit_vote_button').disabled = false;
    $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
          }
        });
     $( "#dialog-message" ).html(data) //here goes your data var (rendered html from your django template)
});
```

Comment: Hm, tried this out and "html: data" doesn't seem to work with the JQuery dialog (I notice it's not anywhere in the API documentation). What I get is a blank modal popup. Edit: got it displaying with $( "#dialog-message" ).html(data); but it's still not exactly the way I want things to work. Thanks for the inspiration though, I'll keep it in my pocket as a backup plan.

Comment: i added your change, which is the way you want to work? You can write your own close function to disable the checkbox and do some stuff

Comment: Was hoping to be able to go through steps 1-4, where step 3 actually takes you to an entirely different page, but this may not even be feasible. I think I'm going to give up and redesign things entirely. Voted up your answer though, thanks.